# 500 (Internal Server Error) angular change(Put) method Api

Tags: angular, django-models, django-rest-framework, angular-httpclient, internal-server-error

I am trying to use put method from Angular to change parameter of availability that i have in my django rest Api, i have django model ClubPlaces with parametres plae_id, name , availability['available','booked'],and i am trying change availablity using button, i have using matdialog  to display a button from another component called toBook but code to change in booking.component.ts file ,

so their appear a problem , 500 Internal Server Error

booking.component.ts:

```
//there is some other methods

openBookInformation(event: Event, place:any){

    event?.preventDefault();

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ToBookComponent,{
      width:'500px',
      height:'500px',
      data: place
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result:any) => {
      
      if(result){
        
        const index = this.filteredPlaces.findIndex(f => f.place_id === result.place_id);
        
        if(index !== -1){
          
          this.clubPlacesService.updatePlaceAv(result).subscribe(updatedPlace => {
            
            console.log('place updated:', updatedPlace);
            
            this.filteredPlaces[index].availability=updatedPlace.availability;
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

toBook.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Inject,Input } from '@angular/core';
import {  MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-to-book',
  templateUrl: './to-book.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./to-book.component.css']
})
export class ToBookComponent {

  place: any;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef:MatDialogRef<ToBookComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data:any)
    {
      this.place = data;
    }

  bookPlace(): void{
    this.place.availability = 'booked';
    this.dialogRef.close(this.place);
  }

}
```

booking.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

export interface ClubPlace{
    place_id:number;
    name:string;
    availability:string;
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn:'root'
})
export class ClubplaceService{
    private apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/club-places/';
    
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

    getClubPlace():Observable<ClubPlace[]>{
        return this.http.get<ClubPlace[]>(this.apiUrl);
    }

    updatePlaceAv(place:ClubPlace): Observable<ClubPlace>{
        const url = `${this.apiUrl}${place.name}/${place.place_id}/`;
        return this.http.put<ClubPlace>(url,place)
    }
}
```

code from backend part :

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import ClubPLace
from .serializers import ClubPlaceSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework import status


class ClubplaceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ClubPLace.objects.all().filter()
    serializer_class= ClubPlaceSerializer
    lookup_field = 'name'
    
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        club_name = self.kwargs.get('name')
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        instances = queryset.filter(name=club_name)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instances, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve_by_id(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        club_name = self.kwargs.get('name')
        place_id = self.kwargs.get('place_id')
        instance = get_object_or_404(ClubPLace, name=club_name, place_id=place_id)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        club_name = self.kwargs.get('name')
        place_id = self.kwargs.get('place_id')
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from .views import ClubplaceViewSet
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('club-places', ClubplaceViewSet,basename='club-place')

urlpatterns = [
  path('club-places/',ClubplaceViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list','post': 'create'}), name='club-place-list'),
  path('club-places/<str:name>/',ClubplaceViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve','put': 'update', 'patch': 'partial_update','delete': 'destroy'}),name='club-place-detail'),
  path('club-places/<str:name>/<int:place_id>/', ClubplaceViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve_by_id','put':'update'}), name='club-place-detail-by-id'),
]

urlpatterns+=router.urls
```

Comment: `club_name = self.kwargs.get('name')` should be `club_name = kwargs.get('name')` shouldn't it? Same for `place_id`. Not sure why you're accessing those values via `self`